# Need to mount a HDD out of a crashed windows 10 laptop to recover files. Error message below:

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

My laptop has a motherboard issue and I can't boot up WIN10 in order to shut down correctly.  When I plug in the HDD into the USB on my linux machine I get this message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdg3 at /media/ice/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdg3" "/media/ice/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdg3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I've tried a few commands I've found on here and no luck.  Any ideas?  I'm new to Linux but I've really enjoyed what I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

The system is most likely trying to protect itself because the HDD is corrupt or etc (which may solve your issue with your Windows 10 computer). You should try what bussbar said to do and mount the volume read-only. This question is also probably off-topic and does not have really anything to do with Ubuntu if this is the case.